# What is the difference between {} and () in std::visit function?

Tags: c++, variant

The following code is basically a more "naive" version of the example on variant found on CPP Reference. It defines a `std::variant` type (line [1]) and uses `std::visit` to iterate through a vector of that type. Here, I used a functor (line [2]) inside the `std::visit` function as an attempt for a better understanding of how `std::visit` works.

What puzzles me the most lies in lines [4] and [5]. It appears that either `Print{}`, with curly brackets, or `Print()`, with parentheses, can serve as the first parameter to `std::visit` function. The later, i.e., `Print()`, is an instantiation and is thus supplying an object as the first parameter, which is comprehensible. I don't quite understand why the former, `Print{}`, works too. Can anyone shed some light on this peculiarity?

```
using var_t = std::variant<int, long, double, std::string>; // [1]

class Print {                                               // [2]  
public:
    void operator()(int arg) {
        std::cout << "Integer is " << arg << '\n';
    }

    void operator()(double arg) {
        std::cout << "Double precision is " << arg << '\n';
    }

    void operator()(long arg) {
        std::cout << "Long type is " << arg << '\n';
    }

    void operator()(const std::string& arg) {
        std::cout << "String is " << arg << '\n';
    }
};

std::vector<var_t> vec = {10, 15l, 1.5, "Hello, World", 900};   // [3]

for (auto& v : vec) {
    //std::visit(Print{}, v);  // [4]
    std::visit(Print(), v);    // [5]
}
```

Comment: It's a different initialization.
`Print{}` uses aggregate initialization, 
`Print()` uses constructor initialization.

Comment: `Print` is an aggregate, so it can be initialized by [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Print()` is a call to constructor of class `Print`. `Print{}` is list initialization of class `Print`.  In this case the difference is only int that list initialization actually would be aggregate initialization and would init members of `Print` if it had any, the constructor would not.

In both cases you pass an instance of `Print`.